# Get the custom post type list of authors

Tags: php, wordpress

My custom post type is resources i need to create a dropdown list with all the authors in the custom post type.. This doesn't quite work can anyone help?

```
<?php
            $post_types     = 'resources';
            $orderby      = 'name'; 
            $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $title        = '';


            $args_autours = array(

              'post_type'     => $post_types,
              'orderby'      => $orderby,
              'show_count'   => $show_count,
              'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
              'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
              'title_li'     => $title,

              'show_option_all'     => 'SERIES'
            );

            $authors_sermon =array();
        ?>
```

//The form with the drop downs. Querying the post below

```
        <form method="post" action="#" id="dropdownauthors">
        <?php query_posts( $args_autours );
                  if (have_posts())  : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    $authors_sermon[] = get_the_author();
                    $authors_sermon = array_unique($authors_sermon);

                   endwhile; 
            echo '<option value="#">Speaker</option>';
                   foreach($authors_sermon as $author) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $author . '">' . $author .'</option> ';

                      }
                 endif;
                 print_r($authors_sermon)
         ?>

                <?php 

                    /* wp_list_authors($args_autours); */

                ?>

            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: what are you getting in the output? are you getting any error?

Comment: No error.. the full list doesn't seem to come out.. this is the print _r version..Array ( [0] => Terran Williams [2] => Roger Haynes  [6] => RBC Ministries [11] => Christo Bredenkamp )

Comment: You have missed the <select> tag

Comment: Hi feroz even with the <select> tag there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

for me it is working as i tried in phpfiddle

once check this one

[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/giq-wce)

Comment: Thanks ferpz the problem is it's not pulling through all the aouthors from a specific custom post type with a specfic category

Comment: nice to hear it, if my answer helps you then accept it so the other people can found it easily

Comment: Hey feroz I'm still stuck on this one.. It doesn't bring in all the authors from the custom post type.. How do i get it to pull the specific taxonomy authors for a  post type.

Comment: as you mentioned in your comment that you are getting this array "Array ( [0] => Terran Williams [2] => Roger Haynes [6] => RBC Ministries [11] => Christo Bredenkamp" is this not complete list?
if not then what is the code in get_author()